# How does the terminal know which function it's to apply?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm pretty new to using the terminal to run commands as well as using bash scripts.  With that said, I'm using subversion as well as an Amazon S3 command line tool.  When I run either svn commands or s3cmd commands in the terminal both work.

When running both in a bash script, the subversion worked, while I seemed to need to first change directories (`cd /Users/my_username/s3cmd-master`), and then run:

`./s3cmd sync -r /Users/my_username/some_folder s3://some_s3_place`

for example, otherwise I'd get an error stating that the command didn't exist (notice the "./" at the start).  I fear that the latter was out of trial and error, based on a Dropbox script which I had.  Could someone please explain why I needed to change directories in the latter case so that I don't have to guess the approach when using third party command line tools in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, re: "which function to apply" -- shell functions are a very specific kind of command, and `s3cmd` typically isn't implemented as one (though it certainly could be wrapped by one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a command that isn't fully qualified, alias expansion occurs, shell functions are searched, builtins are searched, the hash table containing memoized locations from prior PATH lookups is inspected, and then the directories listed in the (colon-delimited) `$PATH` variable are searched.

```
./s3cmd
```

...is fully qualified; it can only refer to an external executable in the current directory (`.`)

```
s3cmd
```

...is not fully qualified; it could be an alias, it could be a shell function, it could be an external command somewhere one of the directories given in the environment variable `PATH`. To find out which it really *is* you can run the command `type s3cmd`.

---

Let's say that you had a shell function named `s3cmd`, which downloaded a default configuration file if you didn't have one in place before running the real `s3cmd`:

```
s3cmd() {
  [[ -e $HOME/.s3cfg ]] || { curl -O "$HOME/.s3cfg" http://example.com/s3cfg || exit; }
  command s3cmd "$@"
}
```

`type s3cmd` would tell you this:

```
s3cmd is a function
s3cmd() {
  [[ -e $HOME/.s3cfg ]] || { curl -O "$HOME/.s3cfg" http://example.com/s3cfg || exit; }
  command s3cmd "$@"
}
```

---

In your particular use case, you probably want to add `/Users/my_username/s3cmd-master` to your PATH. One appropriate place to do this might be `$HOME/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/s3cmd-master
```

Note that you *don't* need to explicitly run `export` here, since `PATH` will already be flagged as exported to your environment.

Comment: I was trying to keep it simple; since the OP doesn't understand `./`, it's unlikely that s/he's set up any aliases or shell functions.  But +1 for the detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer!  So, would this mean that since I don't need to do this for my svn command, that the PATH is defined somewhere?  And, if so, how might I be able to actually locate where this is done?

Comment: @Eric, there's a default `PATH` provided by your operating system (typically something like `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`); exactly where and how it's defined varies, but the idea is that you can always change it in your user account's `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` or such), no matter the details of where/how the default is defined; you should be always overriding it from inside your own account's dotfiles, not tweaking the global default.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks again for taking the time to answer a very noob question AND for not docking me "-1", which is what I was anticipating. :)

Comment: @Eric, ...by the way -- to make changes to `~/.bash_profile` take effect without logging out and back in, you might need to explicitly rerun it: `source ~/.bash_profile`. Note that that only takes effect within the shell where it's run, so restarting your login session is the safe approach.

Answer (score 2):

`./foo` means `run 'foo' from the current directory`.  So if you're not in the directory containing "foo" when you run that command, you'll get an error.

If you just call `foo`, the shell will try to look it up from the path.  If it isn't in the path, you'll get an error.

On Windows `cmd`, the current directory is always in the path, so you usually don't need to call `.\foo`.  But you can, and you may see people who are used to unix-style shells doing that a lot.

Comment: "the path" referring to the colon separated list of directories in `$PATH` that should be searched for executables. You can add `/Users/my_username/s3cmd-master` to this list to be able to run just `s3cmd` from any directory.

Comment: ...also, there are several other things the shell tries before resorting to a PATH lookup. It looks for aliases; it looks for functions; it looks for builtins; it looks in its hash table (which I didn't mention in my answer); etc.

Comment: Just a quick thanks for your response. And, I DID appreciate your straightforward answer, but after thinking about things, I gave Charles the credit, as his solution opened some new doors for me.  Cheers!